# double click to unselect a checked Check List Box c#

Tags: c#

I have a checkListBox in my windows form application and also a button `select all`. I am wondering is there a way to unselect all checked items in my checkListBox when I double click my button? How can I do that? thanks.

This is my button

```
private void selectAllbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){




}
```

Comment: Double-clicking a button is not a good UX solution, because it won't be clear to users that they are supposed to double-click to unselect all. Plus, different mice and OS configurations may recognize double-clicks more or less quickly than others, which makes it a nightmare for testing. A better solution would be to simply have another button to clear all the checked items. Much clearer that way!

Comment: yes write the code for the check all as well as the opposite for deselecting  all.. what's the problem..? there are tons of working examples for this simple task online @DragonBom

Comment: @NateBarbettini, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: lol :D you are still awake :D

Comment: you just need to revert the selection functionality.. On click of `select all` check box that you added to your UI, you need to check if that is `box.checked == false` then just deselect all..

Comment: @AmneshGoel, I am just messing around with the application :) I will give it a try thank. :D

Comment: @DragonBorn Is this a windows forms question? Was the problem solved?

Comment: @RezaAghaei, I decided to add a 'clear' button to my form. Nate was correct, it isn't that clear to the users because they have no idea how this program will work unless you tell them. This work fine now :)

Comment: @DragonBorn good job.